# Can't get any navigation item in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I have a question regarding the navigation bar.

As far as I understand from iOS: A view controller opened by a segue inherits the navigation bar of the parent view controller. Is this correct so far?

Is there a view controller within a stack "owns" the navigation bar in a complex segue stack (e.g. TableViewController that opens a TabBarController that opens ...)?

I very often run into the problem that I don't know where to get the actual navigation item in order to set the title or a bar button item.

In this case, I have the following controllers:

- `TabBarController`
- `EventPostsViewController` -> To display a list of posts, is a tabbed view within the TabBarController
- `CreatePostViewController` -> To write a new post

So within the `EventPostsViewController` I can do this (and it works):

```
class EventPostsViewController: UITableViewController {
    ...
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        ...
        // This solution works, but only for EventPostsViewController
        self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.title = "text"
```

But within the `CreatePostViewController`, which is opened by a segue via `EventPostsViewController`, neither of this solutions work.

```
class CreatePostViewController: UIViewController {
    ...
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        ...
        // Neither of these solutions works
        self.navigationItem.title = "Text"
        self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.title = "Text"
        self.navigationController?.navigationItem.title = "Text"
```

How do I get the actual navigation bar/navigationItem?

Comment: What kind of segue? If it's not a push segue there is no navigationController and thus no navigationItem.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! It is a "Show (e.g. Push)" segue. Isn't push deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

Stupid simple mistake I repeat every time :)

I forgot to link my custom `CreatePostViewController` with the view controller using the interface builder.

[image]

This code now works:

```
class CreatePostViewController: UIViewController {
    ...
    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated);
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)

        // Set title
        self.navigationItem.title = "Write Post"

        // Add Submit button
        var submitButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Done, target: self, action: "submitPost:")
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = submitButton
    }
    ...
}
```